# why doesn't this stop running?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

why is this code running like forever? I want it to stop when all numbers in y_list are near to an integer as I defined in "def C(y)"

```
y_list=[1.0, 3.4 ]
k=1

def C(y):
    return abs(y-round(y)) < 0.15

while not all(C(y) for y in y_list):
    z_list = [y*k for y in y_list]
    k+=1
    print(z_list)
```

Comment: Because you don't change `y_list` inside the loop? Why *would* it stop?

Comment: What is the point of `z_list`? Seems like maybe you want `y_list = [y*k for y in y_list]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't changing `y_list` (and you don't *want* to change it!). And because you're testing the static `y_list` in the `while` loop condition, that loop will never end. But you *are* changing `z_list` so you need to test that `z_list`  meets your condition.

And so that the `while` test doesn't fail on the first loop you need to make `z_list` a copy of `y_list` before the loop starts.

```
y_list = [1.0, 3.4 ]

# Copy the original data
z_list = y_list[:]

def C(y):
    return abs(y-round(y)) < 0.15

k = 1
while not all(C(y) for y in z_list):
    z_list = [y*k for y in y_list]
    k+=1
    print(z_list)
```

**output**

```
[1.0, 3.4]
[2.0, 6.8]
[3.0, 10.2]
[4.0, 13.6]
[5.0, 17.0]
```

Note that I made `z_list` a copy of `y_list` by doing

```
z_list = y_list[:]
```

If I just did

```
z_list = y_list
```

then `z_list` would simply be another name for the same list object as `y_list`, you wouldn't get two separate lists.

---

FWIW, here's another way to write this. We use `itertools.count` so we don't have to update `k` manually, and `map` to call the testing function, which I've given a more meaningful name.

```
from itertools import count

y_list = [1.0, 3.4 ]
z_list = y_list[:]

def almost_int(y):
    return abs(y - round(y)) < 0.15

for k in count(2):
    print(z_list)
    if all(map(almost_int, z_list)):
        break
    z_list = [y*k for y in y_list]
```